# Why $[0,3]/(1,2)$ is not homeomorphism to $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, quotient-set

Clearly $[0,3]/(1,2)=[0,1]+ {\rm point} A+[2,3]$.  How can I prove those are not homeomorphic

Comment: Can you find a point in the quotient that is not closed?

Comment: Please add context to your question, following the advice here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question As it stands, your question does not meet [established quality guidelines for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement).

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{A\}$, where $A$ is the identified set $(1,2)$, seen as an equivalence class, so a point in the quotient $Y:=[0,3]{/}(1,2)$ (under the identification map $q:[0,3]\to Y$), is not closed as $q^{-1}[\{A\}]=(1,2)$ is not closed in $[0,3]$. So $Y$ is not $T_1$ and $[0,3]$ is, being metric.

So they're not homeomorphic.

Note that $Y':=[0,3]{/}[1,2]$ *is* homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.